# asp.net mvc and json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class FileUploaderResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TempFileName { get; set; }

    public FileUploaderResult(bool success, string fileName, string errorMessage)
    {
        this.Success = success;
        //this.RelativeThumbnailUrl = fileName;
        //this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

and following  controller method:

```
    public JsonResult UploadFileAjax()
    {
        var result = new FileUploaderResult(false, string.Empty, string.Empty);
        try
        {
            //...
            result.Success = true;
            result.TempFileName = filename;
            return Json(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            result.Success = false;
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

on client part I try to parse this JSON :

```
                var objResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                alert(objResponse.TempFileName);
```

and it does not work. When I try to show response as is:

```
                alert(response);
```

I got the message with "litter" (

http://ru.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/e8f4D1ciAU8.html

why parseJSON does not work and how to do correctly?

Comment: could you show ur jquery code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are requesting the data as HTML, not plain text or JSON. The browsers wraps the text in the response in a `pre` tag to make an HTML page out of it.

When you request the data, specify the data type `"json"`, then the browser will not try to make HTML out of it, and jQuery will parse it for you and return an object.